# VBA Access -> Excel Output: File Size BALLOON from 3mb to 20mb, why?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm finishing up a program that I built to import an excel to a database, do some manipulations/edits, and then spit back out the edited Excel. Except my problem is that the file size just balloon'ed to a huge amount from approx 3mb to ~19mb.

It has the same record count ~20k. It has ~3 more columns (out of 40+ columns total) - but that shouldn't make the file size x6, should it? Below is the code I use for the output:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Q_Export", acFormatXLS, txtFilePath & txtFileName
```

Any ideas on how I can get that file size a bit more down? Or anyone have a possible indication of what is doing it at least?

Comment: No - it's not the database I'm worried about. That is part of the toolkit programming. All I care about is the output that users will be using. And emailing a 20mb file doesn't sound like fun.

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible reasons that spring immediately to mind;
1) You are importing more records than you think you are.  Check the table after the Excel file has been imported.  Make sure the table has EXACTLY as many records as there are rows of data in Excel.  Often the import process will bring in many empty records, and that data is then exported as empty strings.  To you it looks the same, but to Excel it's information that must be stored, which takes up space.

2) Excel handles NULL values differently than Access does.  If your data has a lot of missing information, it's going to be stored differently when it's imported into Access.  This actually brings us back to Reason #1.

3) When you import data, sometimes it comes in with trailing spaces.  make sure you TRIM() your data before exporting it, to get rid of any potential storage space being used.

Comment: Ok - well, it does have null values in the imported Excel - and I get the feeling that this could be where it comes from, anyway to... well.. clear that space up? It's not the importing more, I have checked the range.

Comment: Is there any formatting in the sheet you're importing?  And are both the import and export using the same version of Excel?  2K7 adds a lot of markups, so if you're importing a 2K3 and exporting a 2K7 then you will definitely see a difference in file size.

Comment: Yes, there is formatting in the sheet. I have some hyperlinks in the table, if I DoCmd.Transferspreadsheet acexport the hyperlinks don't come out.

If I instead do my DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, it comes out with the hyperlinks intact.